# Dump an IMAP Mailbox to a local folder

Tags: email, imap

I need to dump IMAP mailboxes from an IMAP server.
I would like to replicate IMAP folders structure on a specific path.
I would like to dump all emails and sub-folders (and then "sub-emails"), but in a filesystem.

Emails in EML format and, foreach one, a file (MAIL1.EML, MAIL2.EML, etc)
IMAP folder as... folders!

I tried getmail but it does not work as expected (i don't want the qmail-style Maildir...)

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found myself is to use the amazing google library imaputils

https://code.google.com/p/imaputils/

This library have the "iu-dump" utility that make exactly what i am searching about